# How can i fill empty row with (-) separated column header split data using c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

First photo is my current output in excel, second photo shows what i want[image]
[image]

I am having trouble, i am insert a empty row in my dataset below column header names and i wish to fill the empty row with splitted column header name. like (1-600,1-700,1-800 are splitted separate cells
here 1 is year and 600 is weeks same like all

Here is my Code:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDataSet();
    }
    private void GetDataSet()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection);
            string data = null;
            //int i = 0;
            //int j = 0;

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [CAT].[Tables].[LT1005ReportYAS]", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionID", "2603_LT023_13022019174458");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", "2019-01-01");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", "2019-01-21");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", 1030);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            var dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Retailer";
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.RemoveAt(0);
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.RemoveAt(0);


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();
            for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[1, i];
                xlRange.Font.Bold = -1;
                xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                xlRange.Borders.Weight = 1d;
                xlRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }



            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dt.Columns.Count; i1++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1] = dt.Columns[i1].ColumnName;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int s = i + 1;
                for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();

                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[s + 1, j + 1] = data;
                    xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];

                    xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                    //xlRange.Font.Bold = -1;
                    xlRange.Borders.Weight = 1d;

                    xlRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

                }
            }



                xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Retailer.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created");

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Split() to do what you're asking. For example:

```cs
string exampleValue = "1-600";

// This will split the string at the '-' (hyphen) character and produce an array with 2 values.
string[] splitString = exampleValue.Split('-');

Console.WriteLine(splitString[0]); // Expected output: 1.
Console.WriteLine(splitString[1]); // Expected output: 600.
```

Does this help?

Comment: Big thanks for answering me but i wish to do it dynamically.

Comment: @AamirAhmad Dynamically based on what? Do you mean that you want to split every column header in this manner or that you want to change how the headers are split based on some criteria?

Comment: yes dear i want to know how the headers are splitted on some criteria because your string.split() example are not working in my code

Comment: Can you please help me!!..Really i am in trouble